# Raise 'Unable to create group (name already exists)' Error when save model in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm build a model fusion with ResNet50 and DenseNet121 from keras.applications, but raise a error when save the model.
If I use only one network of ResNet50 and DenseNet121, such as DenseNet only, No Problem

fusion with ResNet50 and DenseNet121:

```py
img_input = Input(shape=input_shape)

densenet = app.DenseNet121(
    include_top=False,
    input_tensor=img_input,
    input_shape=input_shape,
    weights=base_weights)
resnet = app.ResNet50(
    include_top=False,
    input_tensor=img_input,
    input_shape=input_shape,
    weights=base_weights)

x1 = densenet.output
x1 = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='dn_gap_last')(x1)
# then x1.shape is (batch, 1024)

x2 = resnet.output
x2 = Flatten()(x2)  # then x2.shape is (batch, 2048)

x = concatenate([x1, x2], axis=-1)
predictions = Dense(len(class_names), activation="sigmoid", name="predictions")(x)
model = Model(inputs=img_input, outputs=predictions)
```

and save model via ModelCheckpoint

```py
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
                 output_weights_path,
                 save_weights_only=True,
                 save_best_only=True,
                 verbose=1,
            )
```

but raise a erro when saving mdoel

```
Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 0.72018, saving model to ./experiments/8/weights.h5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 229, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 212, in main
    shuffle=False,
  File "/home/hqt/chest-x-ray-project/code/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hqt/chest-x-ray-project/code/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2280, in fit_generator
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "/home/hqt/chest-x-ray-project/code/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 77, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "/home/hqt/chest-x-ray-project/code/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 445, in on_epoch_end
    self.model.save_weights(filepath, overwrite=True)
  File "/home/hqt/chest-x-ray-project/code/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2607, in save_weights
    save_weights_to_hdf5_group(f, self.layers)
  File "/home/hqt/chest-x-ray-project/code/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2878, in save_weights_to_hdf5_group
    g = f.create_group(layer.name)
  File "/home/hqt/chest-x-ray-project/code/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py", line 50, in create_group
    gid = h5g.create(self.id, name, lcpl=lcpl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5g.pyx", line 151, in h5py.h5g.create
ValueError: Unable to create group (name already exists)
```

Comment: Seems to be due to layer naming convention in Keras. Check out this issue: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12195

Answer (score 2):

In case If i need to use an op like tf.tile as in your case, I will call it with a lambda layer. So the code that works is as follows

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras import Model

def my_fun(a):
  out = tf.tile(a, (1, tf.shape(a)[0]))
  return out

a = Input(shape=(10,))
#out = tf.tile(a, (1, tf.shape(a)[0]))
out = Lambda(lambda x : my_fun(x))(a)
model = Model(a, out)

x = np.zeros((50,10), dtype=np.float32)
print(model(x).numpy())

model.save('my_model.h5')

#load the model
new_model=tf.keras.models.load_model("my_model.h5")
```

Anyone facing similar issue, please follow the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32672) related to this problem for a final solution. Thanks!

## Edit on 02/04/2020

With the recent code modifications, you could use `tf-nightly` to save the model in "h5" format without any issue as shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras import Model

a = Input(shape=(10,))
out = tf.tile(a, (1, tf.shape(a)[0]))
model = Model(a, out)

x = np.zeros((50,10), dtype=np.float32)
print(model(x).numpy())

model.save('./my_model', save_format='h5')
```

Comment: Hi! I wonder whether the tf-nightly you mentioned in the answer is 2.1 or 2.2? (Since 2.1 is not released already)

Comment: It is 2.2. I guess TF2.2 stable version might be released soon (currently 2.2.0-rc2). [Here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/jvishnuvardhan/dfb8d9f5aaea1dabd06baed8696c50ab/untitled42.ipynb) is a gist for your reference. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Waiting for that to be released :)